# How to check for null or undefined methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Somewhere along the line `jQuery` changed it's handling of non-existent elements. Assume `#nearby` element does not exist, then

```
console.log($('#nearby').html());
```

**A)** In `jQuery <= 1.7.2`, it prints out `null`

**B)** In `jQuery > 1.7.2`, it prints out `undefined`

I am trying to support checking for both cases. The following works:

```
if ($('#nearby').html() === null || $('#nearby').html() === undefined)
{ 
    console.log('nothing here');
}
```

Is there a less ugly way of checking for `null` or `undefined` methods? I tried a boolean check:

```
(`if ($('#nearby').html()))` ...
```

But it didn't work. So, Is there a better way?

**Note** that this is not a check for **undefined/null variables**, for which there are a million answers on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check if an element exists, why not use:

```
If (!$('#nearby').length)
{
    console.log("nothing here...")
}
```

```js
console.log(!$('#nearby').length);

if (!$('#nearby').length)
    console.log("#nearby do not exists!");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In the other hand, if the element exists and you want to check if some method is available for that element, then you can use `typeof`

```js
if ($('#nearby').length && typeof($('#nearby').html) !== "function")
    console.log("html() is undefined!");
    
if ($('#nearby').length && !typeof($('#nearby').foo) !== "function")
    console.log("foo() is undefined!");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nearby"></div>
```

So, in summary, if you want to check if the element don't exists or some method isn't available to use on it, you can do this.

```
if (!$('#nearby').length || typeof($('#nearby').foo) !== "function")
    console.log("Nothing here...")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!$('#nearby').html() || $('#nearby').html() == null || 
  $('#nearby').html() == 'undefined') { 
     console.log('nothing here');
   }
```

that works for me

Comment: This is the code that I have.  Was looking for something more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for both cases using :

```
if (!!$('#nearby').html()) { 
  console.log('nothing here');
}
```

because undefined or null are both false.

Comment: Just add !!    which will convert it too boolean